# How do I mod the latest version of Minecraft on UBUNTU? I am new to LINUX

Tags: permissions, java, launcher, minecraft

I have Minecraft installed and it runs.  But I can only get vanilla 16.4.  I tried following some other websites and their directions... but all I have managed to do is change the permission for the minecraft-launcher folder and add a folder for a new version of minecraft (1.7.10).  I tried then using the minecraft launcher to install 1.7.10 into the new folder, but I get an error O: Minecraft couldn't start.  16.4 still runs... so I didn't screw up minecraft... It just will not install 1.7.10 (or any other version for that matter).  Like I said, new to LINUX, so I would need kind of a detailed explanation, not a "Just check your permissions" - cause I still have trouble doing just that.  Thanks

Comment: "*I would need kind of a detailed explanation*" -- this goes **both ways**.  If you don't explain exactly what it is that you want to do and if you don't explain exactly what steps you've already taken, we are in a poor position to help

Comment: Simple answer:  How do you mod minecraft in Ubuntu.  Actually I just looked and looked and looked until I founf the directories and did what I did in Windows.  Works fine now.  Thanks.  Oh, and you could have just said: The .minecraft directory exists in Ubuntu, just like in Windows and looking in your file viewer and telling it to view hidden files will allow you to see it.  Like I said at the Top: I am new to Linux.  Simple steps dude... you read too much into stuff - not every answer requires a full on list of sudos and apt-gets and --remove

Comment: AskUbuntu is a collaborative effort.  If I had known the answer, I certainly would have answered it.  Actually, I still don't understand your question in the way that it was written.  Clearly nobody else did either if the answer was so easy!  Legible and unambiguous documentation is quite important when you want to communicate with others.  If you have an answer, please post your solution below.  You can still choose to help other people even if you feel somehow wronged by AskUbuntu. Please write to the best of your ability so other people can understand.

Comment: For example, if you were looking for the path of a file, why didn't you just ask something like "What is the path for..." -- If this was what was so hard for you to find, your comment really doesn't help a single poor soul who might be in your same position reading this question in the future.  Even if you think my comment was malicious (it wasn't), can't you be the bigger person and help someone else like yourself?  I do take some offense when someone acts entitled for free help, is too lazy to write clearly and unambiguously, but then refuses to help others when they get what they need.